# How to create offline app for salesforce

Tags: visualforce, app, offline, office-connect

How to create salesforce offline app which allow user to Offline access to Salesforce data also insert data off-line & 
once client will online then data will automatically sync with salesforce.

Answer (score 1):

*P.S - This is a very broad question but I'll anyway provide some pointers to get you started.*

You can use the Salesforce Mobile SDK and SmartSync framework to do so. Depending on the platform and development approach you may want to look at the following examples

1. [Android Native](https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-android/tree/master/native/SampleApps/SmartSyncExplorer)
2. [Android Hybrid](https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-Android/tree/master/hybrid/SampleApps/SimpleSync)
3. [iOS Native](https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-iOS/tree/master/native/SampleApps/SmartSyncExplorer)
4. [iOS Hybrid](https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-iOS/tree/master/hybrid/SampleApps/SimplySync)

The key is to look at the relevant classes

Native

Android class: `com.salesforce.androidsdk.smartsync.manager.SyncManager`
iOS class: `SFSmartSyncSyncManager`

Hybrid

For hybrid, there are [2 ways](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mobile_sdk.meta/mobile_sdk/entity_framework_hybrid_using.htm) of doing this

- `com.salesforce.plugin.smartsync`: The SmartSync plugin offers basic “sync up” and “sync down” functionality. This plugin exposes part of the native SmartSync library. Use this plugin in simpler syncing scenarios to sync large numbers of records rapidly in a native thread, rather than in the web view.
- `smartsync.js`: The SmartSync JavaScript library provides a Force.SObject data framework for more complex syncing operations. This library is based on backbone.js, an open-source JavaScript framework that defines an extensible data modeling mechanism. To understand this technology, browse the examples and documentation at backbonejs.org.